VBUS Filtering for USB-Powered Audio System with Pi Filter
I'm designing an audio system powered by a USB 2.0 connector (5V, 500mA). The system is shown below:

The filtered +5V VBUS power line drives the DAC, LP filter, and audio amplifier. To filter the VBUS noise, I want to use a Pi filter with an inductor and two capacitors. I've decided to use an inductor instead of a ferrite bead due to potential issues the ferrite bead. I've tried online Pi filter calculators (like THIS) to determine the component values, but I'm unsure what Cutoff frequency and Output characteristic impedance to choose. Concerns:

Cutoff frequency: What cutoff frequency should I choose for the Pi filter to ensure effective noise filtering without affecting the audio signal?
Output characteristic impedance: What is the characteristic impedance in my case? Is it the 8 Ohm speaker?
Undamped Pi filter: I've heard that Pi filters can be undamped, leading to resonance issues. How can I determine if my Pi filter needs damping, and if so, how do I damp it?
Voltage regulator: Should I use a voltage regulator to step down the VBUS voltage to around 4V for the audio power supply? Would this help with noise filtering or is it unnecessary?

System Specifications

USB 2.0 power input (5V, 500mA) with Inrush current protection IC
Audio output: 8Ω, 1W speaker
Frequency range: 20Hz to 20kHz
DAC sampling frequency: 44.8kHz

I'd appreciate your help.

The maximum capacitive load that you can put on the USB power rails is 10uF, so this is largely going to define your filter. You can probably get away with more if you are limiting the inrush current, but I'm not sure if there is a provision for that in the USB spec (that document has grown huge!).

Sorry I forgot to mention that I have USB protection IC implemented which has inrush current limiter built in, so no worries about that.

To get around the 10 uF max capacitance, have you considered a say 4.9 V LDO with softstart? It would eat up tens of mV of potential noise and allow you to have a lot of capacitance on your downstream rail?

Is there a LDO that can output 4.9 V at 5V input?

I've stumbled on this post and decided to implement the Pi filter like:

Note however that the the values for L, R and C's are chosen primarily for BOM cost reduction because I already have 2.2uF, 47uF and 0.24 Ohm on my board. I don't really care about the filter characteristics because the author of the answer in the post says: "Overall, if the filter performance is not critical, don't spend your time overanalyzing it[...]".
